# Email2Case attaching to the wrong account

Tags: email2case, case-object, automation

I am having an issue with a user that is using email2case and the case created is being assigned to a particular account to which the email address is not associated (there is no contact with that email address belonging to that account). Am I overlooking something here?
I would also like to know what is the process of case creation used in email2case where the sender (email address) belongs to no account or multiple accounts?

Comment: did you check assignment rules?

Comment: & trigger if any on Case/EmailMessages/EmailService?

Comment: In my org, using On-Demand Email-to-Case, when I submit a case via email using an email address not yet associated to any Contact, the Case is created and the value of `Case.suppliedEmail` is instantiated by SFDC. The Case is not associated with any Account.  The Contact is not created by SFDC. I would tend to agree with @Ganesh that you have some trigger/workflow that is associating the Case to an Account, perhaps by default.  By turning on the debug log for the user associated with email-to-case, you can see whether it is a trigger DML or workflow field update that is making the association.